# Bulk insert csv file with semicolon as delimiter

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm trying to import data from semicolon separated csv file into a SQL Server database. Here is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[waste_facility] 
(
    [Id]           INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [postcode]     VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [name]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
    [type]         VARCHAR (255)   NULL,
    [street]       VARCHAR (255)   NULL,
    [suburb]       VARCHAR (255)   NULL,
    [municipality] VARCHAR (255)   NULL,
    [telephone]    VARCHAR (255)   NULL,
    [website]      VARCHAR (255)   NULL,
    [longtitude]   DECIMAL (18, 8) NULL,
    [latitude]     DECIMAL (18, 8) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

The csv file is shown below:

```
Location Coordinate;Feature Extent;Projection;Postcode;Name Of Facility;Type Of Facility;Street;Suburb;Municipality;Telephone Number;Website;Easting Coordinate;Northing Coordinate;Longitude Coordinate;Latitude Coordinate;Google Maps Direction
-37.9421182892,145.3193857967;"{""coordinates"": [145.3193857967, -37.9421182892], ""type"": ""Point""}";MGA zone 55;3156;Cleanaway Lysterfield Resource Recovery Centre;Recovery Centre;840 Wellington Road;LYSTERFIELD;Yarra Ranges;9753 5411;https://www.cleanaway.com.au/location/lysterfield/;352325;5799275;145.31938579674124;-37.94211828921733;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-37.94211828921733,145.31938579674124/@your+location,17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0
-38.0529529215,145.2433557709;"{""coordinates"": [145.2433557709, -38.0529529215], ""type"": ""Point""}";MGA zone 55;3175;Smart Recycling (South Eastern Depot);Recycling Centre;185 Dandenong-Hastings Rd;LYNDHURST;Greater Dandenong;8787 3300;https://smartrecycling.com.au/;345876;5786853;145.24335577090602;-38.05295292152536;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-38.05295292152536,145.24335577090602/@your+location,17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0
-38.0533129717,145.267610135;"{""coordinates"": [145.267610135, -38.0533129717], ""type"": ""Point""}";MGA zone 55;3976;Hampton Park Transfer Station (Outlook Environmental);Transfer Station;274 Hallam Road;HAMPTON PARK;Casey;9554 4502;https://www.suez.com.au/en-au/who-we-are/suez-in-australia-and-new-zealand/our-locations/waste-management-hampton-park-transfer-station;348005;5786853;145.2676101350274;-38.053312971691255;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-38.053312971691255,145.2676101350274/@your+location,17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0
-38.1243050577,145.2183465487;"{""coordinates"": [145.2183465487, -38.1243050577], ""type"": ""Point""}";MGA zone 55;3977;Frankston Regional Recycling and Recovery Centre;Recycling Centre;20 Harold Road;SKYE;Frankston;1300 322 322;https://www.frankston.vic.gov.au/Environment-and-Waste/Waste-and-Recycling/Frankston-Regional-Recycling-and-Recovery-Centre-FRRRC/Accepted-Items-at-FRRRC;343833;5778893;145.21834654873447;-38.12430505770815;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-38.12430505770815,145.21834654873447/@your+location,17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0
-38.0973208774,145.4920399066;"{""coordinates"": [145.4920399066, -38.0973208774], ""type"": ""Point""}";MGA zone 55;3810;Pakenham Waste Transfer Station (Future Recycling);Transfer Station;30-32 Exchange Drive;PAKENHAM;Cardinia;13Recycling;https://www.futurerecycling.com.au/;367776;5782313;145.4920399066473;-38.09732087738631;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-38.09732087738631,145.4920399066473/@your+location,17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0
```

There are some columns that I don't need, so I create a format file to import the data. The format file is shown as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="255" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="255" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="255" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="255" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="255" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="255" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
  <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="41"/>
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="41"/>
  <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="50"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="postcode" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="name" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="type" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="street" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="suburb" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="municipality" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="telephone" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="website" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="longtitude" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="18" SCALE="8"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="latitude" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL" PRECISION="18" SCALE="8"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Then I tried both bulk insert and bcp `in` - neither of them works.

Here is the bulk insert command

```
USE [waste-facility-locations];  

BULK INSERT [dbo].[waste_facility]   
FROM 'E:\onboardingIteration\waste-facility-locations.csv'   
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'E:\onboardingIteration\waste_facility_formatter.xml',
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      LASTROW = 6,
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      ERRORFILE = 'E:\onboardingIteration\myRubbishData.log');
```

But unlucky some error file were generated. Here is what `myRubbishData.log` error says:

> Row 2 File Offset 1993 ErrorFile Offset 0 - HRESULT 0x80004005

And the actual row stored in `myRubbishData.txt`:

```
;Pakenham Waste Transfer Station (Future Recycling);Transfer Station;30-32 Exchange Drive;PAKENHAM;Cardinia;13Recycling;https://www.futurerecycling.com.au/;367776;5782313;145.4920399066473;-38.09732087738631;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-38.09732087738631,145.4920399066473/@your+location,17z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0;Pakenham Waste Transfer Station (Future Recycling);Transfer Station;30-32 Exchange Drive;PAKENHAM;Cardinia;13Recycling;https://www.futurerecycling.com.au/;367776;5782313;145.4920399066473;-38.09732087738631;https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir//-38.09
```

As you can see, it seems like rows are not correctly separated. So I tried to change the row delimiter to "\n","\r","\n\r","\r\n", none of them work.

And I tried `bcp`. It did not work either.

Here is the `bcp` command I used:

```
bcp [waste-facility-locations].[dbo].[waste_facility] in "E:\onboardingIteration\waste-facility-locations.csv" -f "E:\onboardingIteration\waste_facility_formatter.xml" -T -S "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB" -F 2 -t ";" -r "\n"
```

Then I get an error said somehow the same thing

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
>
> 0 rows copied.
> Network packet size (bytes): 4096
> Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1

One interesting things is, if I create a new excel and choose "Get data" option to import the csv file, the file can be literally correctly parsed.

Basically I can't find what I did wrong here. Can someone help me on this one?

Comment: If there is one (or more) rows with separator or formatting errors, then there is now way to import it via `BULK IMPORT` afaik. You'll have to clean up & correct the data somehow, to make that easier you can use the CSV Lint plug-in for Notepad++ to check formatting errors https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint or just convert the data file to SQL inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server import facilities are very intolerant of bad data and even just formatting variations or options.  In my career, I have literally spent thousands of work-hours trying to develop and debug import procedures for customers.  I can tell you right now, that trying to fix this with SQL alone is both difficult and time-consuming.

When you have this problem (bad data and/or inconsistent formatting) it is almost always easier to find or develop a more flexible tool to pre-process the data into the rigid standard that SQL expects.  So I would say that if Excel can parse it then just use Excel automation to pre-process them and then use SQL to import the Excel output.  If that's not practical for you, then I'd advise writing your own tool in some client language (C#, Vb, Java, Python, etc.) to pre-process the files.

You can do it in SQL (and I have done it many times), but I promise you that it is a long complicated trek.

SSIS has more flexible error-handling for problems like this, but if you are not already familiar and using it, it has a *very* steep learning curve and your first SSIS project is likely to be very time-consuming also.

Comment: I also got a lot of bad data with formatting errors, mostly laboratory and research csv data. That's why I created **CSV Lint** plug-in for Notepad++ to more quickly detect formatting errors. It already saved me a lot of time https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint Btw the plugin can also just convert csv data to SQL inserts.

Comment: @BdR The problem is that technically it is *not* just CSV formatting errors. The SQL importing facilities are actually much more restrictive than that and will fail on perfectly valid CSV files that Excel or even Access would be fine with.